# Unusual behavior of verilog code

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am writing one simple asynchronous sequence detector, but i am getting unusual result at one point. Code is working fine with "`assign a8 =  ((y2&&inp1&&~inp2)||(y1&&inp1));`    " but if i replace above line with following lines in my code its not giving the correct result.

```
assign a6 =  (y2&&inp1&&~inp2);
assign a5 = (y1&&inp1);
assign a8 = a6||a5;
```

Both are technically the same but i am not able to understand why output is not coming correct when i use above lines of code.

```
    module Async_Design(inp1,inp2,outp);
        input inp1,inp2;
        output outp;
        wire y1 ,y2;

    /*assign a6 =  (y2&&inp1&&~inp2);
    assign a5 = (y1&&inp1);
    assign a8 = (a6||a5);*/

    /*Uncommenting the above section and commenting below 
line is not giving correct result*/
       assign a8 =  ((y2&&inp1&&~inp2)||(y1&&inp1));    
        Delay D1(y1,a8);

        nand(a1,y1,1'b1);
        nand(a2,a1,inp1);
        nand(a3,a2,1'b1);
        nand(a4,a3,inp2);
        nand(a5,a4,1'b1);

        Delay D2(y2,a5);

        assign outp = y1;

    endmodule

    module Delay(q,inp);

        output q;
        input inp;
        reg q;
        initial
        begin
            q=1'b0;
        end
        always @(*)
        begin
            q=((inp&&1'b1)||(inp&&1'b1));
        end

    endmodule 

/***********************************************/
TEST BENCH
/***********************************************/

    module Async_Design_Test;

    reg  inp1,inp2;
    wire outp;
    reg[15:0] sequence1;
    reg[15:0] sequence2;
    integer i;

    Async_Design Async(inp1,inp2, outp);

    initial
    begin

        sequence1 = 16'b 0101_1111_0111_1111;
        sequence2 = 16'b 1010_1010_1110_1111;


       for( i = 0; i <= 15; i = i+1)
       begin
          inp1 = sequence1[i];
            inp2 = sequence2[i];
            #6

            $display( " Input1 = ", inp1,  "  Input2 = ", inp2, "  Output = ", outp,);

       end
    end

    endmodule
```

Can anyone help me to understand this behavior as i am new to HDL coding

Comment: Side by side comparison on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Vg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code after change is not valid one. Why?

```
assign a5 = (y1&&inp1);
...
nand(a5,a4,1'b1);
```

What you're trying to do is drive `a5` wire in two different places (btw your compiler should print an error like "can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net `a5`"). And it won't work, since you can drive a wire only in one place. If you change one of this lines, e.g.:

```
assign a6 = (y2&&inp1&&~inp2);
assign a7 = (y1&&inp1);
assign a8 = (a6||a7);
```

you'll get the same output as if you use `assign a8 = ((y2&&inp1&&~inp2)||(y1&&inp1))`.

PS Consider usage of `&` and `|` operators.